# Column values to be replaced with another column's values

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel file with '|' separated values in it:

```
20120615|User 1|mak||ToBeReplaced|20150114
20120615|User 1|mak||ToBeReplaced|20150115
20120615|User 1|mak||ToBeReplaced|20150116
20120615|User 2|mak||ToBeReplaced|20150114
20120615|User 2|mak||ToBeReplaced|20150115
20120615|User 2|mak||ToBeReplaced|20150116
20120615|User 3|mak||ToBeReplaced|20150114
20120615|User 3|mak||ToBeReplaced|20150115
20120615|User 3|mak||ToBeReplaced|20150116
```

I also have another Excel spreadsheet that has the names of all Managers. Eg

```
Manager1
Manager2
Manager3
Manager4
```

Now I want the Managers names to be replaced with the column values ToBeReplaced for each User. i.e

```
20120615|User 1|mak||Manager1|20150114
20120615|User 1|mak||Manager1|20150115
20120615|User 1|mak||Manager1|20150116
20120615|User 2|mak||Manager2|20150114
20120615|User 2|mak||Manager2|20150115
20120615|User 2|mak||Manager2|20150116
20120615|User 3|mak||Manager3|20150114
20120615|User 3|mak||Manager3|20150115
20120615|User 3|mak||Manager3|20150116
```

That should go on replacing for all Users, the use case is

1. If all Managers names are replaced and still more users are remaining, then it should start again from Manager1.

Can anyone help me with an Excel formula or something to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?
[image: Sample]

Column A are your text strings.
B2 formula: `User` (with the white space at the end)
C2 formula: `=MID(A2,SEARCH(B2,A2)+LEN(B2),SEARCH("|mak|",A2)-SEARCH(B2,A2)-LEN(B2))`
D2 formula: `ToBeReplaced`
E2 formula: `=CONCATENATE("Manager",C2)`
F2 formula: `=REPLACE(A2,SEARCH(D2,A2),LEN(D2),E2)`

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite understand what needs to be done for that step, it's more clear if there is before and after. Does OP means something like `20120615|Manager1|mak||ToBeReplaced|20150114`?

Answer (score 0):

Split Text to Columns with pipe as the delimiter and then assuming the first `user1` is in B2 and with `0` in E1 you might put in E2:

```
=IF(B1=B2,E1,"Manager"&RIGHT(E1,1)+1+IF(RIGHT(E1,1)="4",-4))
```

copy down to suit, then use the output to look up actual names in a table from your other sheet.